# Simplified code to check if string is empty before assigning to typed datatable cell

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this line of code that assigns a value to a datatable column only if the value is not empty, this is to preserve the DBNullstatus of the cell if the value passed in is empty.

I am using a typed dataset

```
string i;
if (!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(i))
{
   Dataset.Datatable[0].ColumnName = i;
}
```

Is there a cleaner way (preferably 1 liner) to notate this.

I would like to do something like

```
Dataset.Datatable.ColumnName = (!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(i))?
i : Dataset.Datatable.SetColumnNameNull();
```

or

```
Dataset.Datatable.ColumnName = (!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(i))? i : DBNull.Value
```

Comment: `DataTable` does't have a `Value` property. Are you looking to assign to a column in a row?

Comment: Oops. I meant to say Dataset.Datatable[0].Column

Comment: This is invalid syntax, either fix it or give us more context. If these are custom classes, maybe you can specify that.

Comment: The dataset is a typed dataset. I'm passing an string that is coming from an entity, so the value might or might not be populated.

Comment: You could also make a string [extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) like `public static object OrIfEmpty(this string value, object ifEmpty) { return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? ifEmpty : value; }` and call it like `theCell = i.OrIfEmpty(DBNull.Value);`.

Comment: Actually the issue that I have is that I cannot directly assign DBNull.Value to my typed dataset cell. Otherwise I would have gone with my second approach.

Comment: If the cell is already typed as `string`, then why not just `theCell = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? null : value;`? When you save that back to the db, I'd expect the correct `DBNull.Value` to be written.

Comment: Thanks! Seems to be working for string. Is there any way to do the same for other data types like decimal, int or datetime?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a function to avoid the check for every field you assign. This might be useful if you need this for many different fields

```
private void Assign(DataTable table,string value)
{
  if (!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(value))
  {
     table.Column = value; 
  }
}
```

Call it like so:

```
Assign(Dataset.Datatable,objAssignmentValue.Value);
```

Comment: I'm not sure this compiles, mate.

Comment: Yeah, not sure either. I was doing it based on the sample code. Wasn't sure if these are custom objects or the standard ADO.Net objects. I guess my point was to highlight the approach of consolidating null checks into a wrapper method

Comment: Yeah I see what you're saying, I guess it will be nice if he gives us a bit more info.